# Loading javascript functions to webview in Android Kitkat

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am having problems with loading javascript functions, which are in external file, into webview in Android Kitkat. My approach for earlier versions was that i implemented my own webview client and in method onPageFinisned i called

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + functions);
```

later, when i wanted to call some js method, i call same code, like

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + someFunction);
```

In android kitkat there is new method evaluateJavascript, which replaces my code with calling that javascript functions. My problem is that now this and old approach throw this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined
```

It seems that problem is in loading that javascript functions to webview but i dont know how to load it other way. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What works for me is to have the JavaScript functions inside a Web page, in `<script>` tags:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Android GeoWebTwo Demo</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function whereami(lat, lon) {
        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML=lat;
        document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML=lon;
    }

    function pull() {
        var location=JSON.parse(locater.getLocation());

        whereami(location.lat, location.lon);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
You are at: <br/> <span id="lat">(unknown)</span> latitude and <br/>
<span id="lon">(unknown)</span> longitude.
</p>
<p><a onClick="pull()">Update Location</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I can successfully use `evaluateJavascript()`:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder("whereami(");

  buf.append(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
  buf.append(",");
  buf.append(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
  buf.append(")");

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    browser.evaluateJavascript(buf.toString(), null);
  }
  else {
    browser.loadUrl("javascript:" + buf.toString());
  }
}
```

(both code snippets are from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/GeoWeb2))

This works on old and new versions of Android. Now, in my case, my JavaScript happens to be messing with the DOM, so I needed a Web page anyway. Yours might have an empty `<body>`, with the Web page just there to supply the JavaScript functions.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have an idea about parsing json value from url parameter containing injected javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498500/how-to-json-parse-a-url-parameter-in-android-webview