# Android sdk 19 javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am loading a webpage in an android Webview which contains a several buttons:

< button id="ID" class="class" type="submit">button lable < /button>

There also exists a javascript which should be triggered when you click the button.

Everything works fine on devices with android older than 4.4 . But on 4.4 it does nothing.

Is there a way to solve this problem and make it work also on android 4.4? if so what is the solution?

Here is the webview cod

```
private void init() {
    webview = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            currentUrl = url;
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

    });
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(startUrl);

}
```

Here is the javascript which will be called if I click on a button in the webview

```
 {  window.open('<url which should be opened out of the app>');
 self.location = "<webviewredirecturl>";  }
```

Comment: 4.4 introduced a new version of WebView based on Chromium. See if this page about migrating to it helps: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Comment: I also went trough the documentation. It mentions something about "Handling Touch Events in JavaScript" but I want to know if I don't have access to modify the content of the page, how can I make this works?

Comment: Does the page work in a 4.4 native browser?

Comment: Yes it works. Now it confuses me.

Comment: Post your webview code!

Comment: I added the webview cod and the javascript also... As I observed the self.location = "<webviewredirecturl>"; will be executed but window.open('<url which should be opened out of the app>') not... on android 4.3 or lower it is working

Answer (score 0):

According to to my tests, when your project target is kitkat, the loadUrl method behavior changes.
Instead of being able to execute load on your current page, it systematically open a new page with your url parameter.

For my case, I was sending this url to my already loaded page webview :

```
    javascript:showComment('Content html to add')
```

With target API 18 everything is working, with target API 19, error.

More information about changes with kitkat her :

```
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview
```

Similar Post here :
[Loading javascript functions to webview in Android Kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207748/loading-javascript-functions-to-webview-in-android-kitkat)